# Have a null Async function with react-native firebase and database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have a lot trouble with async functions and assign to a variable on react-native.

So to put in context, I wanna retrieve a data from a database (firebase https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage), so I called a function database(), but I always get null. I realized that this function is asynchronous and I want to get sequentially the data from top to bottom. So I tested it out by printing my code and I got "2" before "1".

What I want is to print the data (from the database), but I get a null

I did many search on google and stackOverflow and I'm struggling on getting this data from asynchronous function.

So how I can I change my code to be able to print the value from the database

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  database()
    .ref(`/${id}`)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      setData(snapshot);
      console.log(snapshot);       //I can see data that I want to retrieve
      console.log(1);
    });
}, []);

console.log(2);
console.log(data) // I WANT TO PRINT HERE WITH THE VALUE expected the data from firebase-database, but have null as value
```

Comment: It looks like you can indeed print the data from the database.  Your comments suggest so.  Why are you trying to print the results other than inside the promise callback?  The callback marks the first point in time when you know results are available - that's what you should be using.

Comment: To make other components to use that data

Comment: You will need to edit the question to make it more clear what specifically you're trying to do, including the other component, and explain what is the challenge in that so far.  Your question, as it stands now, is too vaguely worded to be useful.